# write file to usb with python on linux

Tags: python, file, usb

I apologise if the question is so stupid but I am new in linux and python. 
The point is that I need to write a python script which will detect connected usb stick and write a file to it. I use opensuse(but script shoild work with any linux distro. in ideal case). Current version can detect usb and write a file if that usb is mounted. But on my machine usb is mounted only if I browse it in file manager. Until that usb detected as a partion but without mount point. So, how can I force the system to mount usb or how can I write a file using devname or devpath or another information what I can get from hal manager. I can not use "mount" command because it requires a root permission

Simplified Source code:

```
import dbus, gobject, os

class DeviceAddedListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.hal_manager_obj = self.bus.get_object( "org.freedesktop.Hal", "/org/freedesktop/Hal/Manager")
        self.hal_manager = dbus.Interface(self.hal_manager_obj, "org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager")
        self.hal_manager.connect_to_signal("DeviceAdded", self.added)

    def show(self, name, udi):
        d_object = self.bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.Hal', udi)
        d_interface = dbus.Interface(d_object,'org.freedesktop.Hal.Device')

        if d_interface.QueryCapability("volume"):
            print name
            props = [ "block.device", "volume.label",  "volume.is_mounted", "volume.mount_point", "volume.size"]
            for p in props:
                print '\t', p, " = ",
                try:
                    print d_interface.GetProperty(p)
                except:
                    print "Fail"

    def added(self, udi): 
        self.show("DeviceAdded", udi)
        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(self.property_modified,
            "PropertyModified",
            "org.freedesktop.Hal.Device", 
            "org.freedesktop.Hal",
            udi,
            path_keyword = "sending_device" )

    def property_modified(self, numupdates, updates, sending_device = None): 
        self.show("PropertyModified", sending_device) 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    DeviceAddedListener()
    print "running"
    loop.run()
```

The output when usb plugged in

```
DeviceAdded
block.device  =  /dev/sdb1
volume.label  =  @
volume.is_mounted  =  0
volume.mount_point  =  
volume.size  =  4009722368
```

The output when usb plugged in and mounted

```
    block.device  =  /dev/sdb1
volume.label  =  @
volume.is_mounted  =  1
volume.mount_point  =  /media/@
volume.size  =  4009722368
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why can't you use `mount`? If `mount` doesn't work, why would your solution?

Comment: When I use mount I have a message "mount: only root can do that"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `mount` because the kernel controls mounting partitions within the operating system for security reasons.  You *can* use mount without superuser/administrator privileges. Try something like this:

Make sure that the directory (`/mnt/usb1/`) you are mounting to already exists, and then

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb1 -o noauto,users,rw,umask=0
```

There's also something called autofs that does allow automatic mounting:

http://linuxconfig.org/automatically-mount-usb-external-drive-with-autofs

Comment: Thanks! But I can not mount it for some reason. my '/mnt/' and '/media/' folders are empty and I can not create a new folder with 'mkdir' command without 'root permission' - 'mkdir: cannot create directory `/mnt/usb1': Permission denied'. Of course I can run the script as a root but idea that any user can do it. Just run the script, plugged in a usb and it will write a file to it.

Comment: @user1485818 You have two options: you can try mounting it somewhere besides `/mnt` or `/media`, or you can have an "install" script which needs one-time root access to set up your script.  You will notice that almost all programs on Linux have to be installed by the superuser because they need various permissions to set up their configuration files, etc.

Comment: So, OK. Thanks for your answer! Will do that way.

Answer (score 0):

The HAL it's discontinued, I think so better use UDisks to work with pen USB. Then, you can use methods FilesystemMount and FilesystemUnmount, I create one example here (https://gist.github.com/3037221) and have oficial documantation here (http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/udisks/Device.html#Device.FilesystemMount).